# Ruby HATBM - Negative Filtering behaving strange

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

Lets imaging looking at a Ruby schema with two resources (user & books) which have an HABTM association.

When I am filtering based on this association, whether a user has a book or not, Ruby behaves a bit strange:

```rb
2.5.3 :007 > Contact.includes(:books).count
(4.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contacts"
=> 36880
```

Which is fine, because it returns the total value of contacts with any book association.

```rb
2.5.3 :010 > Contact.includes(:books).where(books: {"id":[1,2] }).count
(34.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "contacts"."id") FROM "contacts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "contacts_books" ON "contacts_books"."contact_id" = "contacts"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "books" ON "books"."id" = "contacts_books"."book_id" WHERE "books"."id" IN (?, ?)  [["id", 1], ["id", 2]]
=> 24864
```

Which is also fine, since it returns all contacts which have book with id 1 or 2.

```rb
2.5.3 :011 > Contact.includes(:books).where.not(books: {"id":[1,2] }).count
(13.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "contacts"."id") FROM "contacts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "contacts_books" ON "contacts_books"."contact_id" = "contacts"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "books" ON "books"."id" = "contacts_books"."book_id" WHERE "books"."id" NOT IN (?, ?)  [["id", 1], ["id", 2]]
=> 0
```

Now this part doesnt make sense, because it should be total - #associations, so 36880 - 24864 leaving me with 12016 records and not 0.

Or what am I missing?

Rails 5.2.2 
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin17]

Comment: Yeah it is weird, the generated sql is very different in the second and third.
the second one `LEFT OUTER JOIN "contacts_books" ON "contacts_books"."contact_id" = "contacts"."id"` and the third one `LEFT OUTER JOIN "contacts_books" ON "contacts_books"."firm_id" = "contacts"."id"`. (Notice the `"contacts_books"."contact_id"` vs `"contacts_books"."firm_id"`). Can you share your models?

Comment: @YanaAgunSiswanto Sorry, thats my bad. I anonymized the model and failed a bit ;)

Comment: Excellent, thanks @engineersmnky thats exactly the issue! adding the ```IS NULL``` resolved it

Comment: are you sure? doing `Contact.includes(:books).where.not(books: {"id":[1,2] }).or(Contact.includes(:books).where(books: { id: nil })).count` gives me the wrong count and my query has `WHERE ("books"."id" NOT IN (?, ?) OR "books"."id" IS NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

the where condition will require the loaded contacts to have at least one book, e.g. it can't check if a book id is in an array if there is no book id.

---

how I debugged this:

I have a small repo when I tried to reproduce your issue:

```rb
Contact.includes(:books).count # 10 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contacts")
Contact.includes(:books).where(books: {"id":[1,2] }).count # 5 (LEFT OUTER JOIN x2)
Contact.includes(:books).where.not(books: {"id":[1,2] }).count # 4 (LEFT OUTER JOIN x2)

# so same as you

# we can find who those missing contacts are:
ids = Contact.includes(:books).to_a.map(&:id) -
  Contact.includes(:books).where(books: { id: [1, 2] }).to_a.map(&:id) -
  Contact.includes(:books).where.not(books: { id: [1, 2] }).to_a.map(&:id)
# I'm getting 3 ids in my case
Contact.where(id: ids).map { |c| c.books.size }
# they all have 0 books
Contact.eager_load(:books).count # 10 (with LEFT OUTER JOIN x2)
# every contact with at least one book
Contact.includes(:books).where.not(books: { id: nil }).count

# some wrong queries
Contact.includes(:books).where(books: {"id":[1,2] }).or(
  Contact.includes(:books).where(books: { id: nil })).size
# returns 8
Contact.includes(:books).where.not(books: {"id":[1,2] }).or(
  Contact.includes(:books).where(books: { id: nil })).size
# returns 7
```

minimal reproduction repo: https://github.com/localhostdotdev/bug/tree/has-and-belongs-to-many-includes-count

Comment: I thought the original poster was asking for understanding more than an actual solution, I may be wrong though.

Comment: made a nice graph to illustrate the has and belongs to many in my data https://gist.github.com/localhostdotdev/659f4c5371d9a2649cda262141c9a88f (one book can have multiple contacts, etc.) (obviously the data isn't perfect but that's the point). if you could point which number doesn't add up I could expand on it

Comment: it is counting distinct records as far as I remember when I ran the queries

Comment: You are correct. My apologies The appropriate inversion as requested by the OP would be `Contact.includes(:books).where.not(id: Contact.joins(:books).where(books: {id:[1,2] }).select(:id).distinct)`